# How do I setup authentication to Google Sheets without being prompted to authorize my script?

Tags: python, google-sheets, authorization, google-sheets-api, google-api-python-client

I'm trying to query Google Sheets through their API using Python and am a little confused getting setup. Using their [documentation guide](https://developers.google.com/sheets/api/quickstart/python), I authenticated myself and have a OAuth 2.0 client id JSON file that I downloaded, and approved access to my app, which is my script right?

However, every time I run my script, I keep getting prompted to authorize my application. I execute the script, and it auto-opens a page in my browser to a Google login-like page where it asks if I want Quickstart to access your Google Account

I copied the credentialing part directly from that page, but am confused as to what to change or do in their APIs and Services Page to get this seamlessly running

```
SCOPES = ['https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets']

if os.path.exists("token.pickle"):
    with open("token.pickle", 'rb') as token:
        creds = pickle.load(token)
    # If there are no (valid) credentials available, let the user log in.
if not creds or not creds.valid:
    if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
        creds.refresh(Request())
    else:
        flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file("googlesheetscreds.json",
                                                         SCOPES)
        creds = flow.run_local_server()
    # Save the credentials for the next run
    with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
        pickle.dump(creds, token)
```

Do I need to change the SCOPES?

Comment: What *kind* of credentials did you request? If they don't grant offline access, then you won't be able to execute without reprompting. (i.e. have you inspected the de-pickled `creds` to see if they allow refreshing?)

Comment: Ah I see. If you're talking about the type of credentials that's listed on the APIs and Services page, it's listed as just `Other` type. If I'm trying to put data into a spreadsheet, am I accessing application data or user data?

Comment: Hmm so the first set of credentials were an OAuth 2.0 client ID, and I went through the wizard to create another set, which ended up being a Service Account Key, which isn't working. I'm now getting this error: `ValueError: Client secrets must be for a web or installed app.`

Comment: @simplycoding When ``googlesheetscreds.json`` is changed to the file of Service Account, your script is required to be modified for using Service Account like ``credentials = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file("### JSON file of Service Account ###", scopes=SCOPES)`` ``service = build(serviceName='sheets', version='v4', credentials=credentials)``. I posted as a comment because I'm not sure whether you want to use Service Account. If I misunderstood your situation, I apologize.

Comment: You can request offline access and save the credentials with the refresh token or use a Service Account to impersonate the user.

Take a look at the library I created and use every time to authenticate on Google APIs [easygoogle](https://github.com/Fryuni/easygoogle). Any thoughts are welcome.

Comment: I'm in the same situation - I am trying to use a Google Sheet as the source of data for automated UI tests. I would like to run them seamlessly without a human interaction to auth. Can you please post an answer on how you solved this?

Answer (score 1):

Looks like you want to use a service account, you should go back to your google cloud console, set it up and download the new JSON file.

Google Documentation about credential types and how to set them up [here](https://developers.google.com/workspace/guides/create-credentials#service-account)

Then you must change your code to load and run with service accounts instead of regular oauth, the problem is the 'InstalledAppFlow', here is the full code:

```
import os.path
import pickle

from google.auth.transport.requests import Request
from google.oauth2 import service_account
from googleapiclient.discovery import build


def create_credential():
    if os.path.exists("token.pickle"):
        with open("token.pickle", 'rb') as token:
            creds = pickle.load(token)
    if not creds or not creds.valid:
        if creds and creds.expired and creds.refresh_token:
            creds.refresh(Request())
        else:
            # flow = InstalledAppFlow.from_client_secrets_file("googlesheetscreds.json", SCOPES)
            # creds = flow.run_local_server()
            creds = service_account.Credentials.from_service_account_file('googlesheetscreds.json')
        # Save the credentials for the next run
        with open('token.pickle', 'wb') as token:
            pickle.dump(creds, token)
    service = build('sheets', 'v4', credentials=creds)

    # Tip: return the spreadsheet already created and re-use it along with your code, 
    # if you create a new one in every request it will leak around 30MB each time
    return service.spreadsheets()
```